# How to enable influx http authentication flag in docker container

Tags: docker, influxdb

Just installed the [tutumcloud/influxdb](https://github.com/tutumcloud/influxdb/) docker image on aws ecs and was wondering how to enable the http authentication flag in the docker container in an persistant way? Adding an user lets the http authentication flag turned off.

Comment: added it as issue on the git repository https://github.com/tutumcloud/influxdb/issues/59

Answer (score 0):

You can [obtain the influxdb.conf file](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) from the Influx DB Docker by running this command on your local machine:

```
my_local_machine$ docker run --rm influxdb influxd config > influxdb.conf
```

Then you can modify the influxdb.conf file by [setting auth-enabled to true](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#set-up-authentication):

```
[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8086"
  auth-enabled = true
```